# Unexpected behaviour while using then with Mono<Void>

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

When combining many `Mono<Void>`s using `.then(Mono<Void>)` they don't run in the expected order.

Can somebody explain the difference between the working and nonworking code below?

Working code

```java
StepVerifier.create(
        repository.incrementCounter(bucket, timeStamp)
                .then(repository.incrementCounter(bucket, timeStamp))
                .then(Mono.just(1).flatMap(t -> repository.resetCounter(bucket, timeStamp)))
                .then(Mono.just(1).flatMap(t -> repository.getCounter(bucket, timeStamp))))
        .expectNext(0L)
        .verifyComplete();
```

non-working

```java
StepVerifier.create(
        repository.incrementCounter(bucket, timeStamp)
                .then(repository.incrementCounter(bucket, timeStamp))
                .then(repository.resetCounter(bucket, timeStamp))
                .then(repository.getCounter(bucket, timeStamp)))
        .expectNext(0L)
        .verifyComplete();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor), your repository should return cold `Mono`s (aka "lazy"), but you're most probably starting the call even before returning it.

You can use `Mono.defer` to make it cold.